# What is the difference between include and parsedinclude

Tags: php, php-include

What is the difference between using

```
   <?php include("filename.inc"); ?>
```

and

```
    <%parsedinclude(filename.inc)%>
```

Both work, but I'm curious about the **< ?** and **< %**  convention, and this is a hard question to phrase for Google.

And also the difference between *php include* and *parsedinclude*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, `<?php` is the normal PHP open tag while `<%` is a variant of it that is used in Nucleus CMS (an open-source blog management software package written in PHP).

---

Regarding the second question, `parsedinclude` is a function in Nucleus CMS, and is not valid in normal PHP.

Function of `parsedinclude`: (quoted from Nucleus CMS Documentation)

> Includes a file into the output. The contents of the file is parsed by the Nucleus skin/template parser, so you can use skin/templatevars. (see phpinclude and include for other include options)

Function is `include`: (quoted from Nucleus CMS Documentation)

> Includes a textfile into the output. The contents of the file is not parsed in any way, so you cannot use skin/templatevars or use PHP code (see `parsedinclude` and `phpinclude` if you want parsed includes)